# Proof of alternative parameterization of Weibull Survival Model

Tags: survival, weibull-distribution, exponential-distribution

In Parametric Survival Models by German Rodrıguez (hyperlink at bottom), it is stated the Exponential and Weibull models can be parameterized in a linear form (with time parameterized as $\log(T)$).

> The exponential distribution is related to the extreme-value distribution with the proof following immediately from the change of variable.

I found this derivation:

$$\eqalign{
t &= \log x \\
x &= e^t \\
\frac{dx}{dt} &= e^t\\
g(t) &= f(e^t) \frac{dx}{dt} = e^t e^{-e^t}, \quad -\infty \lt t \lt \infty.
}$$
However, regarding the relationship between the Weibull and the extreme value distribution he states that "the proof follows again from a change of variables; start from $W$ and change variables to $Y = \alpha + \sigma W$, and then change to $T = e ^Y$."

I have tried for a while to derive this statement, but even after looking at a number of different sources I cannot seem to figure it out!

http://data.princeton.edu/pop509/ParametricSurvival.pdf

Comment: Found the answer here (Point 28): https://www.randomservices.org/random/special/ExtremeValue.html#exp